# NoMethodError in FoodItems#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I got this error today, when I didnt have it yesterday. The image url is nil when I try to list all the items, but when I go to the show.html the image loads fine.
[image]

here is the foodItems index

```
  <div class="food-items" id="food_items">
<% @food_items.each do |food_item| %>
  <div class="food-item">
    <div class="food-item__wrapper">
      
      <%= link_to image_tag(@food_item.image_url, class: "food-item__image"), food_item %>
        <%= render food_item %>
      <p>
        <%= link_to "Show this food item", food_item %>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

here is the code for show.html

```
  <div class="recipe">
<h2 class="recipe__title">
  <%=@food_item.name %>
</h2>
<div class="food-item__container">
    <%= image_tag(@food_item.image_url, class: "food-item__image-lg") %>
  </div>
  <%= render @food_item %>
<div>
  <%= link_to "Edit this food item", edit_food_item_path(@food_item) %> |
  <%= link_to "Back to food items", food_items_path %>
  <%= button_to "Destroy this food item", @food_item, method: :delete %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you've used a `@food_item.image_url` instead of `food_item.image_url`. You're getting your global and local variables mixed up.

A very common mistake. An alternative is avoiding using instance variables in your views, and instead passing in local variables from the controller. But it requires a bit more code, and it's up to you whether you think that's a good pattern to follow.